# Disable transactions in my Spring Batch job

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-batch

I need to insert a record in my database so another system can read that record. After that, I will write (with my ItemWriter) the response I recieve from that system in a CSV file.

My problem is that the system can't read the record since Spring Batch is transactional. How can I disable that property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to disable transaction enforcement, that can open you up to a  serious data integrity problem.  Even a 1% error issue can easily cause cause ten's of thousands, or even tens of millions of incomplete or bad records. Especially if say the one of the databases you are interacting with, or file systems you are writing to become unavailable.   Which over time WILL happen.  It would also break the job retry features.

A better option would be to break the process up into multiple steps, or jobs so the transaction boundaries fit your process.   So one of them write out to this other database, and then the next step or job does the reading and writing to the file.

Answer (score 3):

Disable spring batch transaction:

1. User .transactionAttribute(attributes()) method from AbstractTaskletStepBuilder with a parameter DefaultTransactionAttribute.
2. Build DefaultTransactionAttribute object with transaction propagation.

Example:

```java
@Bean
public Step springBatchStep() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("springBatchStep")
        ...
        .reader()
        .processor()    
        .writer()
        .transactionAttribute(attributesForTransaction())
        ...
        .build();
}
    
private DefaultTransactionAttribute attributesForTransaction() {
     DefaultTransactionAttribute attribute = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
     attribute.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED.value());
    attribute.setIsolationLevel(Isolation.DEFAULT.value());
    return attribute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch is highly opinionated Framework. You can split Step or do your job inside `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction. Or choose alternative less restrictive Framework.